# How to replace a string using JS?

Tags: javascript, regex

Somewhere in the html file I have the following lines :

```
/*my lines*/ $(function(){i=1;}); /**********/
```

I need to dynamically replace this lines using `js` with this

```
/*my lines*/ $(function(){i=2;}); /**********/
```

---

This is what I tried

```
var outerHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
outerHTML = outerHTML.replace("/*my lines*/","/*my lines*/$(function(){i=2;});");
```

But my regex is not correct. How can I replace it ? How to locate the substring that starts with `/*my lines*/` and ends with `/**********/` ?

Comment: You only want i=1 replaced with i=2? Why don't you outerHTML.replace("i=1","i=2"); Also what do you mean with "But my regex is not correct"?

Comment: Because, i=1 may not be unique. I have `/*my lines*/` string to make sure I am replacing the right i=1

Comment: Also, I do not know what is inside the `/*my lines*/ $(function(){i=1;}); /**********/` . It may be anything. I need to locate the string based on its beginning `/*my lines*/` and ending `/**********/`

Comment: Okay you could try: {/*REPLACE*/i=1;} outerHTML.replace("/*REPLACE*/i=1","/*REPLACE*/i=2");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a regular expression at all, that's a string. The `replace` method doesn't try to turn the string into a regular expression, it will just replace the first occurance of the string.

You need to escape the `*` characters in the regular expression, and the `/` characters if you use a regular expression literal:

```
outerHTML = outerHTML.replace(/(\/\*my lines\*\/)[^\/]+(\/\*+\/)/g,"$1 $(function(){i=2;}); $2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
console.log(str.replace(/\/\*my lines\*\/.*\/\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\//,"/*my lines*/$(function(){i=2;});"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use quote to declare regex. Because in your code, javascript think that you use a `string` instead of a `regex`.

```
outerHTML.replace(/\/\*my lines\*\//g,"/*my lines*/$(function(){i=2;});");
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php) will provide your answer:

> Each HTML element has an innerHTML property that defines both the HTML
>   code and the text that occurs between that element's opening and
>   closing tag. By changing an element's innerHTML after some user
>   interaction, you can make much more interactive pages.
>
> However, using innerHTML requires some preparation if you want to be
>   able to use it easily and reliably. First, you must give the element
>   you wish to change an id. With that id in place you will be able to
>   use the getElementById function, which works on all browsers.
>
> After you have that set up you can now manipulate the text of an
>   element. To start off, let's try changing the text inside a bold tag.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
    document.getElementById('boldStuff').innerHTML = 'Fred Flinstone';
}
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText()' value='Change Text'/>
```

However, this is with user interaction, you could change it so that this function will be called in another function wich will trigger this.